# Induction help ($a_n \lt 2^n$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

so I'm having trouble solving this question..

Define the sequence $a_0$, $a_1$, ... as
$$
a_i =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if $0 \le i \le 2$} \\
a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}+a_{i-3}, & \text{if $i>2$}
\end{cases}
$$
Using complete induction, prove that $a_n \lt 2^n$ for every inter $n\ge2$.

What I got is this so far:

Base case: $n=2$: $a_2=2$   $\lt$   $2^2=4$

So base case holds.

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose P(k) holds (i.e. $a_k\lt2^k$)

Induction Step: P(k+1) holds (i.e. $a_{k+1}\lt2^{k+1}$)

\begin{align}
a_{k+1} & = a_{k+1-1}+a_{k+1-2}+a_{k+1-3} \\
 & = a_{k}+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2} \\ 
 & \lt 2^k+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2} \\
\end{align}

I am confused how I should finish off the proof from here. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are supposed to do this using *strong* induction, you are supposed to be assuming that $P(l)$ holds for each $l\leqslant k$. So:\begin{align}a_{k+1}&=a_k+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}\\&\leqslant2^k+2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}\\&<2^k+2\times2^{k-1}\\&=2^k+2^k\\&=2^{k+1}.\end{align}